# When I use partials the site crashes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, bootstrap-5

I tried adding partials to my program but for some reasons it doesn't work, either I am doing something wrong or idk cause i've looked everywhere and everytime I to use <%- include('////') %>
the it shows me this error:

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\partials\navbar.ejs'`

This is the js file:

```
const { publicDecrypt } = require('crypto');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const redditData = require('./data.json');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'/views')); 
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening to port 3000");
})

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('home');
})

app.get('/r/:subreddit', (req,res) => {
    const { subreddit } = req.params;
    const data = redditData[subreddit];
    if(data){
    res.render('subreddit', {...data});
    }
    else{
        res.render('notfound',{ subreddit })
    }
})
app.get('*', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('notfound');
})
```

This is the EJS file for a webpage

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=,, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><% name %> </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <%- include('/partials/navbar.ejs') %> 
      
    <h1>You are browsing <%= name %> subreddit </h1>
    <%   for(let post of posts){ %>
        <h2> <%= post.title %></h2>
        <h3> by <%= post.author  %></h3> 
        <%  if(post.img){ %>
            <img src="<%=post.img%>">
        <%  } %>    
    <% } %> 
    

y

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the EJS file for my partial (It is a navbar made with bootstrap);

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Links</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/r/soccer">Soccer</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/r/mightyharvest">Mighty Harvest</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/r/chickens">Chickens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: remember that `include` [is always relative to template file that invokes it](https://ejs.co/#docs), that said and as I don't know the structure, and as an example, it's in a root folder, use `../partials/navbar` - the `..` is the same as `./../` that means, from the current node, go back one. (same as `./../..` would be,  the current node, go back two)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, apparently the problem was that instead of using include('./partials/navbar) i did it without the "." before the "/".